# DNN Problem: Dynamic Registration, Paypal, and User Creation

Tags: module, dotnetnuke, payment-gateway, registration

I'm having a problem with the module Dynamic Registration for DNN.

The module is set up with form completion events in such a way that a user gets redirected to paypal and on completion of payment a user gets created and an email is sent out.

I also have it set up so that an email gets sent out on completion of payment, just to test that the module knows when payment has been completed.

I tried going through the process with the payment gateway (Paypal) enabled - the email gets sent out, but the user does not get created. When I disable the payment gateway, however, a user does get created as well as the email is sent out.

Is there something I'm missing here that is making the module not realize it needs to create the user?

The fact that the module sends out the email makes me think that it should also trigger the Uesr Creation event.

Any ideas/hints as to how Dynamic Registration works with Paypal or how I might be able to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

When the user returns to your site from paypal you must have Friendly URL's turned on or the site can't read the data sent back from paypal.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following information at http://www.datasprings.com/Products/ProductForums/tabid/727/forumid/3/tpage/1/view/topic/postid/4581/language/en-US/Default.aspx#4581

> When PayPal integration is turned on:
>   The user is redirected to PayPal based on the information and settings within your PayPal Payment gateway.  This includes the PayPal login, sandbox or standard gateway, and payment information/additional parameters.
>   Completion events do not get fire off initially
>   How do completed events get fired off?
>   When PayPal is enabled Dynamic Completion Events need to be ‘linked’ to PayPal IPN codes. In short, this means that you will specify within the PayPal payment gateway section which ‘completion events’ should be fired off basically conditionally upon which IPN code PayPal will send to your registration form.
>   For example: Maybe you want to setup a completion event to add the user to a security role, but you only want this to happen when the payment is completed. You would first create the completion event, and then you would ‘link it’ within the PayPal payment gateway section under ‘Form Completion Events / PayPal Payment Status’ 
>   For example: Maybe you want to setup a ‘Payment failed’ email to be sent to the administrator if a subscription payment fails. You would first create the completion event, and then you would ‘link it’ within the PayPal payment gateway section under ‘Form Completion Events / PayPal Payment Status’

Comment: Thank you for your help, very good points to look into when setting up paypal with dynamic registration. However it was a detail we overlooked as there were no instructions saying Friendly URLs had to be turned on.